# Matlab plot of several digital signals

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I'm trying to find a way to nicely plot my measurement data of digital signals.

So I have my data available as csv and mat file, exported from an Agilent Oscilloscope. The reason I'm not just taking a screen shot of the Oscilloscope screen is that I need to be more flexible (make several plots with one set of data, only showing some of the lines). Also I need to be able to change the plot in a month or two so my only option is creating a plot from the data with a computer.

What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to this picture:
[image: Goal]
The only thing missing on that pic is a yaxis with 0 and 1 lines.

My first try was to make a similar plot with Matlab. Here's what I got:
[image: What I have so far]

What's definitely missing is that the signal names are right next to the actual line and also 0 and 1 ticks on the y-axis.

I'm not even sure if Matlab is the right tool for this and I hope you guys can give me some hints/a solution on how to make my plots :-)

Here's my Matlab code:

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

MD.RAW = load('Daten/UVLOT1 debounced 0.mat');  % get MeasurementData

MD.N(1) = {'INIT\_DONE'};
MD.N(2) = {'CONF\_DONE'};
MD.N(3) = {'NSDN'};
MD.N(4) = {'NRST'};
MD.N(5) = {'1V2GD'};
MD.N(6) = {'2V5GD'};
MD.N(7) = {'3V3GD'};
MD.N(8) = {'5VGD'};
MD.N(9) = {'NERR'};
MD.N(10) = {'PGD'};
MD.N(11) = {'FGD'};
MD.N(12) = {'IGAGD'};
MD.N(13) = {'GT1'};
MD.N(14) = {'NERRA'};
MD.N(15) = {'GT1D'};
MD.N(16) = {'GB1D'};

% concat vectors into one matrix
MD.D = [MD.RAW.Trace_D0, MD.RAW.Trace_D1(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D2(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D3(:,2), ...
    MD.RAW.Trace_D4(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D5(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D6(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D7(:,2), ...
     MD.RAW.Trace_D8(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D9(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D10(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D11(:,2), ...
      MD.RAW.Trace_D12(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D13(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D14(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D15(:,2)];

cm = hsv(size(MD.D,2)); % make colormap for plot

figure;
hold on;

% change timebase to ns
MD.D(:,1) = MD.D(:,1) * 1e9;

% plot lines
for i=2:1:size(MD.D,2)
    plot(MD.D(:,1), MD.D(:,i)+(i-2)*1.5, 'color', cm(i-1,:));
end

hold off;

legend(MD.N, 'Location', 'EastOutside');
xlabel('Zeit [ns]');        % x axis label
title('Messwerte');         % title
set(gca, 'ytick', []);      % hide y axis
```

Thank you guys for your help!
Dan

EDIT: 
Here's a pic what I basically want. I added the signal names via text now the only thing that's missing are the 0, 1 ticks. They are correct for the init done signal. Now I just need them repeated instead of the other numbers on the y axis (sorry, kinda hard to explain :-)
[image: Almost what I want]

Comment: Hey I don't understand what you mean with the 0,1 ticks on the y-axis. What I see is that the "jumps" inside your different lines are not at the same places as the given graph. For the labeling check the [documentation about adding text to graph](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-to-graphs.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. With the 0, 1 ticks I meant that when the "high-level" of the signal has a 1 on the y-axis and the "low-level" has a 0 on the y-axis. So the y axis would have several 0s and 1s on it. Take the signal on the very bottom for example. You can't really know what value it has. That's why on the y-axis it should say 0 and a little higher 1.

Comment: That is easily achieved. If you want that turn on the y-axis (grid on) and define yourself a new y-axis. THis is done by using the "axes" and `set()` function. I will post a solution. Give me a moment.

Comment: If you have DSP System toolbox can you try using dsp.LogicAnalyzer scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as written in my comment to the question. For appending Names to each signal I would recommend searching the [documentation of how to append text to graph](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-to-graphs.html). There you get many different ways how to do it. You can change the position (above, below) and the exact point of data. As an example you could use:

```
text(x_data, y_data, Var_Name,'VerticalAlignment','top');
```

Here `(x_data, y_data)` is the data point where you want to append the text and `Var_Name` is the name you want to append.

For the second question of how to get a y-data which contains `0` and `1` values for each signal. I would do it by creating your signal the way, that your first signal has values of `0` and `1`. The next signal is drawn about `2` higher. Thus it changes from `2` to `3` and so on. That way when you turn on y-axis (`grid on`) you get values at each integer (obviously you can change that to other values if you prefer less distance between 2 signals). Then you can relabel the y-axis using the [documentation of axes](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html) (check the last part, because the documentation is quite long) and the `set()` function:

```
set(gca, 'YTick',0:1:last_entry, 'YTickLabel',new_y_label(0:1:last_entry))
```

Here `last_entry` is `2*No_Signals-1` and `new_y_label` is an array which is constructed of `0,1,0,1,0,...`.

Comment: Thanks! The 'YTickLabel' setting is what I needed. In combination with the text command I have the plot/graph I wanted :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For viewing y axis, you can turn the grid('on') option. However, you cannot chage the way the legends appear unless you resize it in the matlab figure. If you really want you can insert separate textboxes below each of the signal plots by using the insert ->Textbox option and then change the property (linestyle) of the textbox to none to get the exact same plot as above.

Comment: Grid is a good idea, I forgot about that! The textboxes are an option, I was hoping there's something more automated though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the end result and all my code, in case anybody else wants to use the good old ctrl-v ;-)

[image: Result]

Code:

```
clear;
close all;
clc;

MD.RAW = load('Daten/UVLOT1 debounced 0.mat');  % get MeasurementData

MD.N(1) = {'INIT\_DONE'};
MD.N(2) = {'CONF\_DONE'};
MD.N(3) = {'NSDN'};
MD.N(4) = {'NRST'};
MD.N(5) = {'1V2GD'};
MD.N(6) = {'2V5GD'};
MD.N(7) = {'3V3GD'};
MD.N(8) = {'5VGD'};
MD.N(9) = {'NERR'};
MD.N(10) = {'PGD'};
MD.N(11) = {'FGD'};
MD.N(12) = {'IGAGD'};
MD.N(13) = {'GT1'};
MD.N(14) = {'NERRA'};
MD.N(15) = {'GT1D'};
MD.N(16) = {'GB1D'};

% concat vectors into one matrix
MD.D = [MD.RAW.Trace_D0, MD.RAW.Trace_D1(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D2(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D3(:,2), ...
    MD.RAW.Trace_D4(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D5(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D6(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D7(:,2), ...
     MD.RAW.Trace_D8(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D9(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D10(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D11(:,2), ...
      MD.RAW.Trace_D12(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D13(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D14(:,2), MD.RAW.Trace_D15(:,2)];

cm = hsv(size(MD.D,2)); % make colormap for plot

figure;
hold on;

% change timebase to ns
MD.D(:,1) = MD.D(:,1) * 1e9;

% plot lines
for i=2:1:size(MD.D,2)
    plot(MD.D(:,1), MD.D(:,i)+(i-2)*2, 'color', cm(i-1,:));
    text(MD.D(2,1), (i-2)*2+.5, MD.N(i-1));
end

hold off;

%legend(MD.N, 'Location', 'EastOutside');
xlabel('Zeit [ns]');        % x axis label
title('Messwerte');         % title
% make y axis and grid the way I want it
set(gca, 'ytick', 0:size(MD.D,2)*2-3);   
grid off;
set(gca,'ygrid','on');
set(gca, 'YTickLabel', {'0'; '1'});
ylim([-1,(size(MD.D,2)-1)*2]);
```